# 18S rRNA sequence

Tags: pcr

I have this phenomenon that the human 18S rRNA reverse transcribed with polydT oligos serve as faithful RTPCR normalizers, tested with better known house keepers. I want to know what I'm amplifying exactly, so where can I find the reference sequence for mammalian rRNAs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for reference sequences, RefSeq is a good bet.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=18S+ribosomal+RNA+AND+srcdb_refseq%5BPROP%5D